# Conditional reset method "if disable ignore not disable reset" angular

Tags: angular, angular6, angular9, angular13

```
<div>

     <div>
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="name" [disabled]="editData"
     </div>
  <div>
  <label>address</label>
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="address" 
  </div>
</div>

<button (click)=add() >add</button>
<button (click)=edit()>edit</button>
<button (click)=reset()>reset</button>
```

**Note:- On add() both fields should be reset but on edit only address field should be reset by without disturbing previous value in it (ignore disabled field)**

**ts file**

> reset(){ this.name=""; this.address="";
>
> }

**by doing this all fields are getting reset**

Comment: You can add a flag "edit" in your reset method like this : 
reset( edit:boolean){ 

this.name=""; 
if(flag){
this.address="";
}
}

and call your reset method with reset(false) or reset(true)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
reset(): void{ 
   if(!this.editData) {
     this.name = "";
   }else{
   this.address = this.formvalue.address;
}
}
```

Comment: Please read "[answer]" and its linked pages. See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct, it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your `.ts` file, only reset the address field not the name.

```js
reset(): void{ 
   this.address = "";
}
```

If you want to reset only the address field, when name field is disabled you can do something like this:

```js
reset(): void{ 
   if(!this.editData) {
     this.name = "";
   }
   this.address = "";
}
```

Comment: Here one way its correct but resetting if previous also. On edit there is some value that should get reset for this.address

Comment: I don't understand, can you explain it a bit more?

Comment: Here we are editing the form mean we are having values already for this.address= something. now if I do this.address=""  its all get reset along with the previous values.

Comment: `this.address = "";` replace this whatever you to set value as `this.address = this.something;`

Answer (score 0):

.ts file

```
  add() {
    this.name = '';
    this.address = '';
  }
  edit() {
    this.name = this.name;
    this.address = '';
  }
  reset() {
    if (!this.editData) {
      this.name = '';
    }
    this.address = '';
  }
```